# Get JSON API form docker host

Tags: javascript, json, web

I build qBittorrent from Dockertools box. And qBittorrent have a API **get torrentlist** . It's like that :

```
GET /query/torrents HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: 127.0.0.1
Cookie: SID=your_sid
```

But i run it in this host : http://192.168.99.100:8080/ so i use loadJSON() of javascript to catch what i want . But it's always fail . 
This in console :

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.99.100:8080/query/torrents?filter=uploading&appid=f782f1c06749ea791dcb5d22219adf068a0d16a5a2c7b6686b17459562eb6b4f. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

my code here :

```
var torrent_peer;

function loadJSON(url, callback) {
  var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if (xobj) {
    xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.open('GET', url, true); // Replace 'my_data' with the path to your file
    xobj.withCredentials = true;
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
        callback(xobj.responseText);
      }
    };
    xobj.send();
  }
}

function load() {
  loadJSON("http://192.168.99.100:8080/query/torrents?filter=uploading&appid=f782f1c06749ea791dcb5d22219adf068a0d16a5a2c7b6686b17459562eb6b4f", function(response) {

    var actual_JSON = JSON.parse(response);
    console.log(actual_JSON);
  }, 'jsonp');
}
```

i read some question but it doesn't work. So any one can help me . Thank a lot !

Answer (score 0):

That is because the API does not specify the header that allows you to access it outside the allowed origin. This is probably a security protection of Chrome. Try running

`chrome --disable-web-security`.

But be careful, by enabling this, you are vulnerable to websites.

Another way to fix this is to add the header into the application's API. I am not sure that your application will allow to add it.

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Comment: how to run this chrome --disable-web-security